# Get the count of "in stock" product variations for a variable product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock, product-variations

I'm trying to make a snippet for functions.php file that shows only one price of selected variation, thus omitting the price range displayed along with variation price on single product page. I'm using the following code:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'my_remove_variation_price' );
$product_variations=$product_variable->get_available_variations;
function my_remove_variation_price() {
  global $product;
  if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price' );
  }
}
```

The problem is when you have, for instance, two variations of single product and one goes out of stock, this script hides the price of one remaining variation on single product page.
I was thinking maybe to have a COUNT of available variations per product and use IF to show them using standard single product template. Or maybe you have better idea how to solve that?

Comment: Maybe a better solution would be to add a "from" before the lowest price variation.. have a look here:https://iconicwp.com/blog/change-price-range-variable-products-woocommerce/

Comment: I'm already using From on shop pages. On single product I dont want multiple prices at the same time (From: $xx & actual variation price). Thats exactly how woo shows variation prices. What Im doing is showing From on all list pages, and when it comes to single product page, the script tests if product is variable and shows the price template (single or variable). I also have a script that syncs stock quanitites which turns some variations in or out of stock. The problem is that when variable product has only one variation on stock, it doesnt show product price.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the "in stock" variations count of a variable product on single product pages you can:

1) Use only php and Woocommerce WC_Product methods:

```
global $product;
$count_in_stock = 0;

if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
    $variation_ids = $product->get_children(); // Get product variation IDs

    foreach( $variation_ids as $variation_id ){
        $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
        if( $variation->is_in_stock() )
            $count_in_stock++;
    }
}

// Your condition
if( $count_in_stock <= 1 ){
   // Do something
}
```

2) Use a SQL query with few php (quick and lighter):

```
global $wpdb, $product;
$product_id = $product->get_id();
$count_in_stock = 0;

if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
    $count = $wpdb->get_col("
        SELECT count(p.ID) as in_stock_count FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
        WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'product_variation' AND p.post_parent = $product_id
        AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_stock_status' AND pm.meta_value LIKE 'instock'
    ");

    $count_in_stock = reset($count);
}

// Your condition
if( $count_in_stock <= 1 ){
   // Do something
}
```

Both codes are tested and work.

Comment: can I use it somehow through functions.php?

Comment: The line is missing a bracket

if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ))

Answer (score 1):

This is my Final working code, achieved with the help of LoicTheAztec answer:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'my_remove_variation_price' );
function my_remove_variation_price() {
    global $product;
    $count_in_stock = 0;

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' )) {

        $variation_ids = $product->get_children(); // Get product variation IDs

        foreach( $variation_ids as $variation_id ){
            $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
            if( $variation->is_in_stock() )
                $count_in_stock++;
        }   
    }

    if( $count_in_stock <= 1 ) 
    {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price' );
    }   

}
```